# Windows Azure - Can Azure Websites run native C++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, azure

I have some `C++` code that I am calling from my `C#` application. I am looking to move this application to `Azure Websites`, and I'm trying to understand if my native `C++` code will be able to be called or not.

I am successfully using the methods described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694038.aspx) to run my native code in the cloud (or rather my locally cloud development environment , but this doesn't seem to apply to `Azure Websites`.

Does anyone know any references that may show me how to successfully execute `C++` code on `Azure Websites` (not `Azure Web Roles`)?

Comment: Should take about 5 minutes to find out?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Websites is full trust so yes you can.

However it isn't true full trust as they place certain security barriers to ensure you don't affect other sites running on the same hardware.

As such it depends on what your C++ DLL as to whether it will work. I will say that if you try to gain access to memory outside of what you allocated or direct access to the root drive or something similar you shouldn't be accessing, your code will throw a security permission error or fail.

Comment: Hard to imagine any piece of C++ that doesn't need "direct access to memory".

Comment: I just edited the post. I should have said any memory that your application didn't initially allocate. (i.e. jumping across to memory another application is using)

Comment: Does this restriction include App Service Environments? It claims to be fully isolated and dedicated environment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro